# RegEx as a conditional in a if else statement returns unexpected result

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to pass a argument to a function, and check if the argument consists of one or two letters or numbers. If they are, evaluate to `true`, if they aren't, evaluate to `false`.

The arguments that has to evaluate to `true` are `'PP', 'P', 'M', 'G', 'GG', 'XS', 'S', 'L', 'XL'` and a range of numbers from `'30'` to `'50'`, but there maybe more. What they have in common: they never have more than 2 characters,  so I came up with this regular expression, but I'm not sure if this is 100%.

```
/^[0-9]{1,2}$/gi.test('09');   // returns 'true'
/^[a-z]{1,2}$/gi.test('AZ');   // returns 'true'
/^[0-9]{1,2}$/gi.test('Word'); // returns 'false'
/^[a-z]{1,2}$/gi.test('Word'); // returns 'false'
```

On their own, they work just fine. But when I use it in a `if...else` statement, I don't get the expected result:

```
function example(value) {
  if (value === /^[0-9]{1,2}$/gi.test(value) || /^[a-z]{1,2}$/gi.test(value) ) {
    // do stuff...
  } else {
    // do other stuff...
  }
}

example('AA');   // returns 'true'
example('99');   // returns 'false', expected 'true'
example('Word'); // returns 'false'
```

What I'm getting wrong? Also, how can I improve this code?

Comment: As you've stated above `.test()` returns true/false. So why do you expect a comparison against `value` would succeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect. In your `if` statement you are testing:

```
value === /^[0-9]{1,2}$/gi.test(value)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
'99' === /^[0-9]{1,2}$/gi.test('99')
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
'99' === true
```

Which is `false`.

You just need to take out the `value ===` part.

Comment: I feel dumb now.

Comment: Don't worry mate it's easy to miss simple things, we all do. :)